# Progress Bar for Asynchronous Loading >1000 images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous routine to generate and load over 1000 images. 
The Progress Bar works well after Load event is triggered and informs the user while each picture is shown. 
Given the # or images, program takes a long time to generate and assign the images to their respective . How do I include a progress Bar for this first stage?
If I had a few images, then the setup stage would be fast and progress bar would not be needed. But as the size of images increases, a progress bar for the setup stage is needed. Any one could help?

Below you find the code I have

```
            var loaded = 0; var i = 0; var k = 0; var massimo = 5;
            var expected = massimo;
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#main1").html("<h1>" + "Preparing Data" + "</h1>");
            });
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                var page = 0, loaded = 0, perpage = massimo, main = $('#main'), expected = perpage,loadMore = $('#loadMore');
                loaded = 0; expected = 0;
                var deferred = $.Deferred().resolve();
                for (q = 0; q <= 4000; q++)
                {
                    deferred = $("#main").showImage(rthis(), expected, deferred);
                    expected++; $("#ChartDiv1").html("");
                }
                NProgress.start();
                page++;
                $("#ChartDiv1").remove();
            });

            $.fn.showImage = function (src, contexpt, deferred)
            {
                var elem = $(this);
                var result = $.Deferred();
                var holder = $("<div id=\"" + "id_" + contexpt + "\" class=\"photo\" />").appendTo(elem);
                var img = $("<img id=\"" + "img_" + contexpt + "\" >");
                $("#id_" + contexpt).append(img);
                img.load(function ()
                {
                    i += 1; 
                    deferred.always(function ()
                    {
                        var xloaded = loaded + 1;
                        loaded++; NProgress.set(loaded / expected);
                        img.hide().appendTo(holder).delay(1000).fadeIn('fast', function () { result.resolve(); });
                        k += 1;
                    });
                });
                img.attr('src', src);
                img.attr('hidden', true);
                return result;
            }

        function rthis()
        {
            onLoadDoc();
            chart2Img(chart1, img);
            return img.src;
        }
```

Comment: So what is the problem with the code you have? What is NProgress?

Comment: Think of it like this, if Stage 1 - Set up data for Images, and Stage 2 - Load Images and display progress bar.   I can display progressbar for Stage 1, but no progressbar for Stage 1. NProgress is a tool i.e. progress bar, with two parameters, Counter and Total Possible Counter